# oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource run a command for every new connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling, pool

I would like to execute an ALTER SESSION command on every new connection coming from a particular oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource connection pool.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying to an application server, check the configuration options, in many cases you can configure some "initial SQL" there.

If you cannot do is that way, wrap `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` with a custom DataSource at the application level, then use that custom DataSource in the rest of your application. Something like:

```
public class InitialSqlDataSource implements DataSource {
    private DataSource delegate;
    private String initialSql;


    public InitialSqlDataSource(DataSource delegate, String initialSql) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.initialSql = initialSql;
    }

    public void setDelegate(DataSource delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void setInitialSql(String initialSql) {
        this.initialSql = initialSql;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = delegate.getConnection();
        if (connection != null && isNew(connection)) {
            issueInitialSql(connection);
        }
        return connection;
    }

    protected boolean isNew(Connection connection) {
        // Logic to find out if connection is a new one
        // or a previously pooled connection. In the worst
        // case you can approximate this logic by always returning 
        // true. This will issue the initial SQL on every retrieval 
        // of a connection from this DataSource. This will
        // add some overhead, but will work in many cases.
        return true;
    }

    protected void issueInitialSql(Connection connection) {
        // A typical JDBC statement execution, adapted to
        // your particular needs
        ...
    }

    // Delegate every other method to this.delegate
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom code on each new connection (or, in worst case, on each "get" from connection pool). On the other hand, if feasible, you can create LOGON TRIGGER on particular schema.

Comment: So the question is how do I do custom code on each new connection?  Doing anything on each "Get" will have too much of an impact.  Doing LOGON trigger is not an option for multiple reasons.

Comment: @MK. Which alter session is so costly that you can't afford one extra call per transaction?

Comment: @gpeche I don't remember any more, but generally I don't want to find our the hard way which ones are expensive and would rather do things right w/o spending hours analyzing performance later.